# PowerShell Cannot get element from HTML

Tags: import, getelementbyid, getelementsbytagname, getelementsbyclassname

I encountered a problem today while trying to get a value from a website using PowerShell.

This is the [website](https://mods.factorio.com/mods/TpTheGreat/TpTheGreats%20Large%20Roboport%20Logistics%20Area).

I am trying to get the number "90" here, that in the webpage itself is the value of "Downloaded" (this number might be a little bigger when you look at it if there are more downloads):[Screenshot of the element i am trying to return](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eZpcE.png)

```
<span title="Downloads" class="mod-card-info-tag" data-reactid=".0.0.0.2.0.0.2.2">
<div class="mod-card-info-tag-label" data-reactid=".0.0.0.2.0.0.2.2.0">90</div>
```

This is the PowerShell code i used to try and get the number "90" from the element above (i know i should use ".innertext" in the end, i just used the get-member to see if any object was found):

```
$URI = "https://mods.factorio.com/mods/TpTheGreat/TpTheGreats%20Large%20Roboport%20Logistics%20Area"
$HTML = Invoke-WebRequest  -Uri $URI

($HTML.ParsedHtml.getElementsByTagName("div") | Where{ $_.className -eq ‘mod-card-info-tag-label’ }) | Get-Member
```

When calling for the element by tag name like in my code above, I get an empty object.
I tried lots of things without any success.

It'll be really great if any of you could take a look and check if you are able to solve my problem.
Thanks a lot!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about another approach:

```
 $URI = "https://mods.factorio.com/mods/TpTheGreat/TpTheGreats%20Large%20Roboport%20Logistics%20Area"
 $HTML = Invoke-WebRequest  -Uri $URI
 $arr = $HTML.AllElements.Item(9).innerHTML  -split ' = '

 $myObj = $arr[1].replace("`n"," ") 

 $myObj = $myObj.replace(";","") | ConvertFrom-Json

 $myObj.mod.mod.downloads_count
```

Comment: Thanks a lot!! 
It works!!

Just one question - Do you have an idea why my approach didn't work? i saw many suggestions of using this method online  but it seemed to not work for me

Comment: I think that for plain-html web sites, your approach should work just fine, but, in this case, the site seems to use `react` and `javascript` to render the site in execution time.